# Custom form validation using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5, form

Recently I have been doing a bit of work with `Contact Form 7` and `Wordpress`. I've begun looking at form validation using `jQuery` and I've been trying to write a script that is as efficient as possible.

I'm wondering if someone could take a look at my code here: https://jsfiddle.net/javacadabra/6mpo9h9z/4/ and let me know if I'm going about things the right way or if what I am doing is messy and bad practice.

The form operates like this at the moment:

- If an input fails the `regEx` check it adds a class called `error`
- If an input passes the `regEx` check it adds a class called `success`
- If an input is empty when the form is submitted it adds a class called `empty`

The form will only submit if the `error` class is not on any input fields and if at least one checkbox is selected. This is my submission code:

```
$('#get-started').submit(function(e) {
  var isValid = false;
  //Check at least on option is selected
  var checked = $('input:checked').length > 0;

  //Loop through all text fields
  $("input[type='text']").each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('error') || $(this).val() == "") {
      if ($(this).val() == "") {
        empty($(this));
        isValid = false;
      }
      isValid = false;
    } else {
      isValid = true;
    }
  });

  //If everything is valid submit && checked is true
  if (isValid && checked) {
    return false; //for testing;
  } else { //else show error
    return false;
  }
});
```

This is my `regEx`:

```
function nameCheck(name) { //Checks if a name contains letters only
  var condition = new RegExp(/^[A-Za-z -]+$/);
  return condition.test(name);
}
```

Whenever a user clicks out of an input field I check to ensure the input is valid like so:

```
$('input[name="first-name"]').focusout(function() {
  if ($(this).val() != "") { //Only do if user has input text
    var isOk = nameCheck($(this).val());
    if (!isOk) { // Incorrect 
      incorrect($(this));
    } else { // Correct
      correct($(this));
    }
  }
});
```

I have 3 methods which will set the input according to the state (correct, incorrect, empty)

```
//Correct input
function correct(input) {
  input.parent().find('.hint').hide();
  input.parent().find('.fa-times').hide();
  input.parent().find('.fa-check').show();
  input.parent().find('.fa-exclamation').hide();
  input.removeClass('error');
  input.addClass('success');
  input.removeClass('empty');
}
//Incorrect input
function incorrect(input) {
  input.parent().find('.hint').show();
  input.parent().find('.fa-times').show();
  input.parent().find('.fa-check').hide();
  input.parent().find('.fa-exclamation').hide();
  input.addClass('error');
  input.removeClass('success');
  input.removeClass('empty');
}

//Empty input
function empty(input) {
  input.parent().find('.hint').show();
  input.parent().find('.fa-exclamation').show();
  input.parent().find('.fa-check').hide();
  input.parent().find('.fa-times').hide();
  input.addClass('empty');
  input.removeClass('error');
  input.removeClass('success');
}
```

Basically I'd like to continue with this pattern and add more fields (some with slightly different checks on the input). However before I do I just want to be sure that I'm writing clean, maintainable code. Once I am happy with my `client-side validation` I am going to then implement similar checks on the `server-side` with `PHP`.

Please feel free to offer your suggestions on the above. Also this post may be helpful for anyone who is looking to implement their own custom form validation with `jQuery`.

Also, this is my `HTML`:

```
<div id='application-form' class='com col-md-8 form-horizontal'>
  <form id='get-started' action='#' method="post">

    <!-- First and Last Name -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>First Name <span class='hint'>(Name can only contain letters)</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="first-name" id="first-name"><i class="fa fa-times"></i><i class="fa fa-check"></i><i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Last Name <span class='hint'>(Name can only contain letters)</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="last-name" id="last-name"><i class="fa fa-times"></i><i class="fa fa-check"></i><i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Options -->
    <div class='form-group'>
      <div class='col-md-12'>
        <label>Choose an option: <span>(You must choose at least one option)</span></label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="option-group[]" value="option 1" /> Option 1
        <input type="checkbox" name="option-group[]" value="option 2" /> Option 2
        <input type="checkbox" name="option-group[]" value="option 3" /> Option 3
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Submit -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type='submit' name='submit' class='apply btn btn-primary' value="Get Started" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would you want to do custom jQuery validation, is there a specific application reason? from what I see here you can customize HTML5 validation without as much hassle.

Comment: Specific application reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery lets you select multiple elements with a `,`. So you can shorten this quite a bit by doing:

```
$('input[name="first-name"], input[name="last-name"]').focusout(...
```

because the code within those focusout handlers is exactly the same.

Another place you could do that:

```
input.parent().find('.hint, .fa-times').hide();
```

---

Also, although it doesn't make much of a difference here, it would be faster (and easier for you) to select the `first-name` and `last-name` by their ID:

```
$('#first-name, #last-name').focusout(...
```

You might as well, because it's shorter, quicker and easier - you have the ID on the element, so you might as well use it!

---

jQuery lets you string functions together. When you use `addClass()`, jQuery returns the element that you added the class to, so you can do:

```
input.addClass('error').removeClass('success');
```

---

```
 if ($(this).hasClass('error') || $(this).val() == "") {
   isValid = false;
 } else {
   isValid = true;
 }
```

There's no need to set `isValid` as `false`, because you declared it like `var isValid = false;`, so it's already false! Also, if isValid *is* false, there's no need to keep on looping through the `input`s, because it's going to be false anyway, so you should escape the loop early if is `false`

Instead, you could do something like:

```
if ($(this).hasClass('error') || $(this).val() == "") {
   return false;
} else {
  isValid = true;
}
```

---

In your `correct()` and `incorrect()` functions, you do `input.parent()` twice. Ideally, you should store this in a variable first, to avoid jQuery looking for the parent twice, eg:

```
function correct(input) {
  var $parent = input.parent();
  $parent.find('.hint, .fa-times').hide();
  $parent.find('.fa-check').show();
  input.removeClass('error').addClass('success');
}
```

---

With all this in mind, your revised code would be something like: (I also moved the functions to the top of the page, but that's just personal preference and makes it easier to see all your functions at once)

```js
function nameCheck(name) { //Checks if a name contains letters only
  var condition = new RegExp(/^[A-Za-z -]+$/);
  return condition.test(name);
}

function correct(input) { //correct input
  var $parent = input.parent();
  $parent.find('.hint, .fa-times').hide();
  $parent.find('.fa-check').show();
  input.removeClass('error').addClass('success');
}

function incorrect(input) { //incorrect input
  var $parent = input.parent();
  $parent.find('.hint, .fa-times').show();
  $parent.find('.fa-check').hide();
  input.addClass('error').removeClass('success');
}

//Check first-name and last-name are valid every time user types a character into the input field
$('#first-name, #last-name').focusout(function() {
  if ($(this).val() != "") { //Only do if user has input text
    var isOk = nameCheck($(this).val());
    if (!isOk) { // Incorrect 
      incorrect($(this));
    } else { // Correct
      correct($(this));
    }
  }
});

//Check everything is valid before the form submits
$('#get-started').submit(function(e) {
  var isValid = false;
  //Check at least on option is selected
  var checked = $('input:checked').length > 0;

  //Loop through all text fields
  $("input[type='text']").each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('error') || $(this).val() == "") {
      return false;
    } else {
      isValid = true;
    }
  });

  //If everything is valid submit
  if (isValid && checked) {
    alert('submitting...')
    return false; //for testing;
  } else { //else show error
    alert('do not submit');
    return false;
  }
});
```

```css
#application-form label {
  display: block;
}
#application-form label span {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#application-form input[type='text'] {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
#application-form i.fa {
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  bottom: 11px;
  font-size: 22px;
}
#application-form i.fa-check {
  color: green;
  display: none;
}
#application-form i.fa-times {
  color: red;
  display: none;
}
#application-form .hint {
  display: none;
}
#application-form .success {
  background: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.33);
  border: 1px solid green;
}
#application-form .error {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.33);
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#application-form input[type="submit"] {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 200px;
  border: none;
  padding: 12px 0px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div id='application-form' class='com col-md-8 form-horizontal'>
  <form id='get-started' action='#' method="post">
    <!-- First and Last Name -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>First Name <span class='hint'>(Name can only contain letters)</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="first-name" id="first-name"><i class="fa fa-times"></i><i class="fa fa-check"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Last Name <span class='hint'>(Name can only contain letters)</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="last-name" id="last-name"><i class="fa fa-times"></i><i class="fa fa-check"></i>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Options -->
    <div class='form-group'>
      <div class='col-md-12'>
        <label>Choose an option: <span>(You must choose at least one option)</span>
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="option-group[]" value="option 1" />Option 1
        <input type="checkbox" name="option-group[]" value="option 2" />Option 2
        <input type="checkbox" name="option-group[]" value="option 3" />Option 3
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Submit -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type='submit' name='submit' class='apply btn btn-primary' value="Get Started" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your feedback, very helpful and informative!!! Greatly appreciated